# Why run Handler in main Looper thread

Tags: android, android-handler

I read that the Android [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler) can be used to communicate with the main [Looper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper) thread to post messages that will interact with the views(since only main thread can interact with views there)

But I often see code like the example below that run the [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler) in the main thread. Why is that a good think to do, it feels unnecessary unless there is a delay like `postDelayed(new Runnable()...`

Any explanation on this would bee nice

```
public class TaleDemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);

        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        new Tale("Hello runnables!").tell();
                    }
                });
                new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        new Tale("Hello runnables!").at().tell();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        new Handler().post(new TestRunnable());
        new Handler().post(new TestStaticRunnable());

        new Handler().post(new TestAbstractRunnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Tale("Hello abstract runnable!").tell();
            }
        });
        new Handler().post(new TestInterfaceRunnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Tale("Hello test interface runnable!").tell();
            }
        });

        new Tale().at().tell();
    }

    class TestRunnable implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Tale("Hello testRunnable!").tell();
        }
    }

    static class TestStaticRunnable implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Tale("Hello testStaticRunnable!").tell();
        }
    }

    abstract class TestAbstractRunnable implements Runnable {

    }

    interface TestInterfaceRunnable extends Runnable {

    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you get this code from? It's covered in Handlers! Nobody should program like that.

Comment: Just reading code at GitHub and found it there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handler is not used just to communicate with the *main* Looper.

`Looper` is a class that loops over a queue of messages and dispatches them, each instance works with one `Thread`.

A `HandlerThread` is a `Thread` that also has a `Looper` attached to it.

The "main" `Thread` of your application is also a `HandlerThread`.

When you instantiate a `Handler` with the empty constructor, the `Handler` will be attached to the `Looper` of the `Thread` in which you are creating the instance. If, for instance, you create a `Thread` in `onCreate` of an `Activity`, then the `Handler` will be attached to the main (UI) `Thread` because the lifecycle callbacks are executed there.

When you call `post(Runnable)`, the `Runnable` will be run on the thread the `Handler`'s `Looper` is attached to. So, if you create a `Handler` in one of the lifecycle callbacks of your `Activity`, then no matter which `Thread` you post the `Runnable` from, it will always be executed on the main `Thread`

This is the most common usage and it is what your code does, but it's not the only one. For instance you could instantiate a `HandlerThread`, then from the `Activity` lifecycle callbacks you could post a `Runnable` that performs very long operation and it will not block your UI because it will be executed on a different `Thread`.

Another usage of `post(Runnable)` (and sometimes a universal dirty fix for weird UI bugs) is to call it from the main thread just with the purpose of delaying the execution until after the whole method had been executed.

```
fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    Handler().post {
        // code here is executed after `onCreate` has returned
    }
    // code here is executed before the one posted on the Handler
}
```

Comment: Thanks, if i do `runOnUiThread(new Runnable()..` in the `onCreate` it will run immediately, how come the `Handler` as you say, run after the `onCreate`? the `runOnUiThread` is using `Handler` internally right??

Comment: `runOnUiThread` will use the `Handler` only if you call it NOT from the main thread, if you call it from the main thread it will execute the `Runnable` without posting it to the `Handler`. Btw, in Android Studio you can left click on a method holding ctrl and it will jump to the source ;)

Comment: Ohh Good to know, thanks I think I understand your the best :)

Comment: No problem, if you have more doubts feel free to ask